# Shell Script for AWS EC2 init

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, boto

I'm trying to initialize a AWS EC2 instance using a shell script. My ultimate goal is to automate this process with boto (the python SDK) and so far I have a simple test script that will run a new ubuntu instance, and then with the shell script will update and download some tools (that works fine) but then I try to have the script create a folder, create a file and ultimately run an AWS cli command to download a file from an S3 bucket.

Once the instance is created, I can ssh in and run the commands that create the folder, the file and download the file from the bucket, but, the script won't do that for me and I can't figure out why.

My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install awscli
mkdir ./test_folder 
echo -e "data" > ./test_folder/test_file
aws s3 ls
```

For the purpose of this post I replaced access key data with "data" so ultimately the s3 command would not work but if someone can help me understand why the ***mkdir*** and ***echo*** commands won't run I'm sure I can figure the rest out.

Comment: shouldn't the apt-get be ran with sudo priviledges?

Comment: Add `set -x` to the script and see what output you get? Do the `apt-get` lines work? Are you sure you know what directory you are executing that script in? Does using an absolute path help anything?

Comment: the apt-get commands work fine. The script is actually passed in as a string into a variable in python that then uses that syntax to call it as a sh script upon initialization. I've tried absolute paths and the result is the same. I tried `set -x` but nothing happened.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happened"? With `set -x` in place you should capture stderr and inspect what's printed. Also, I'd recommend you debug line by line.

Comment: agreed, if "nothing happened" then you've got bigger problems. Try the first line like `#!/bin/bash -x`. Maybe that will help. Good luck.

Comment: I guess I should add the script works fine when I run it from my terminal. I also managed to get the `mkdir` and `echo` functions to work. However I can't manage to get the `aws s3` to be called when the instance initializes.

Comment: Is the script being passed as the user-data so that it is run as root the first time the instance boots? If not, what process is running the script? What user is the script run as? What is the current working directory of the script? Is the output of the script (errors) sent somewhere you can see it?

Comment: It is passed as user-data so that it is run as root. I think I've narrowed down the problem to this: I'm unable to have it run non native commands. i.e if I have `apt-get install python-pip` that works fine, and pip is installed upon bootstraping the instance, however if I also attempt to run `pip install boto` this won't happen. TBH I'm completely new to most of the things I'm dealing with for this project so there are many reasons this could be going wrong. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out, thanks for the help. For non native commands I needed to specify the user using `su 'user' -c 'command'` that allowed me to run commands like `pip install boto` and `aws s3 ls`. Hope if anyone runs into this problem this will help!